# Smallest N-dimensional ellipsoid containing a given ellipsoid and a point

Tags: geometry, ellipsoids

Warning: I am not a mathematician, so excuse me if the problem at hand seems trivial or incomplete.

So, I am working on the following problem: I have to find the smallest (i.e smallest volume) N-dimensional ellipsoid that contains an existing $N$-dimensional ellipsoid and a given point. (This point will lie on the surface of the new ellipsoid.)

The known ellipsoid is described by the general equation:

$$
(x-x_0)^TM_1(x-x_0) \le 1
$$

The unknown ellipsoid would similarly be:
$$
(x-x_0)^TM_2(x-x_0) \le 1
$$

and would completely contain the ellipse given by $M_1$ and a point $x_{new}$.

So the following should be true:

$$
(x_{new}-x_0)^TM_2(x_{new}-x_0) = 1
$$

and gives a first equation to solve the problem. Now however I do not know how to use the other information I have (i.e. that the second ellipsoid should completely contain the first ellipsoid and be the smallest ellipsoid with this property).

I have done some reading and have not found a way to solve this. I suppose one could treat this as a "smallest ellipsoid containing a set of points" problem and solve it this way. But I wondered if there is an analytical way to solve this. It seems there should be, but I am a little rusty in this topic so could not come to an answer myself.

Here a visual representation of the problem:
[image: growth step of Ellipse to contain new computed point]

Comment: Such an ellipsoid is not unique (if I am not mistaken, there is an $n-1$-dimensional family of ellipsoids with the required property). Do you have some optimality condition in mind?

Comment: It is required that the volume is minimized, but apart from that, I have no further constraints. Would this be enough to completely define the problem, or did you already account for this property? (this is what I meant with smallest ellipsoid, will add it to the question)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Ellipsoidal Toolbox](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-46.pdf)?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I did not see that link before, however it was really helpful in gaining some more ideas. I still am not sure how to solve the problem, but I think that the condition about the touching ellipsoids can be thought as imposing the minimum distance between both ellipses equal to 0.

Comment: @Borja There may be algorithms about the smallest ellipsoid that contains two given ellipsoids. A point can be thought of as a degenerate ellipsoid

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo so I searched for such algorithms and found exactly the solution to the given problem above. In case anyone is interested, it can be found in the following report from S.B. Pope, point 10 : [Pope](https://tcg.mae.cornell.edu/pubs/Pope_FDA_08.pdf).
I will add it to the post just in case the link no longer works in the future.

Comment: @Borja You may want to take a look at Blanchini & Miani's [Set-Theoretic Methods in Control](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-17933-9)

Comment: Some Matlab + CVX code: [Minimum volume ellipsoid covering union of ellipsoids](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch08_geometric_probs/html/min_vol_union_ellip.html)

Comment: Take a look at section 8.4.1 of [Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)